# Facebook Link in Feed

Tags: facebook

Just wondering, when I'm trying to add a link in my feed manually here's what it looks like.

[image]

And

[image]

It shows, the site's logo, title, caption, and description

But when I entered other site it shows this,

[image]

So was wondering, what's the requirement or how did it show?
How did the logo appears and how to output the title, caption, and the description of the site?

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done through meta tags that need to be set in the `<head>` element. Facebook has good documentation and examples, [take a look at this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol).